# Subclipse: confusing menu options

Tags: android, svn, subclipse

I've been using subclipse for the past few weeks. I'm confused about a few options on the context menu for the folders within repository in the *SVN Repository Exploring* perspective and didn't find any decent documentation to answer these. (I have referred to http://help.collab.net/index.jsp?topic=/org.tigris.subclipse.doc/topics/toc.html but it is not really detailed)

1. What is the difference between "Import" & "Export"? From what I understood, both copy the files from workspace to repo. Also, how are these different from Team--> Share (which is how I have been adding new projects)
2. A colleague has put it a few C files in the repo. I'd like to check these out with the jni folder of an existing Android project. However, I can only check these out AS A NEW PROJECT. Is there any ways to just check out files in any folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) My version of Subclipse provides an extension for Eclipse's "Import" submenu in the Navigator -- that's how you check out projects -- but not the "Export" menu, so I'm not sure about your question here. The "export" subcommand of Subversion itself provides you with a copy of your source without any of the invisible ".svn" directories in it.

2) No, with Subclipse, you have to check out a whole project.

Comment: From Subclipse help on *Import*: "This option allows you to import files and folders into the repository, making the resources available for checkout." So not sure how this is different from Team--> Share, or effectively the same.

Comment: Thanks for your answers about export & the checking out. I was able to export files to where I wanted, but as you wrote, they lost they are no longer in version control. It kind of sucks that you cannot checkout files wherever you want.

Comment: Indeed, I guess that's kind of confusing; the Eclipse "Import" wizard for Subclipse item does the opposite of what "svn import" does! As far as checking things out anywhere: Eclipse lives or dies by its workspace, as do a number of other IDEs. If you want a less structured development environment, there's always Emacs :)